# How to center a 1200px div above a full-width image element

Tags: html, css

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate, I couldn't find an answer using the keywords I thought to try. I have a site built where the main header image is built using an `<img>` tag. I do this so that the image element can define the height of the header container and be responsive.

Like so:

```
<div class="header">
  <img src="bg.jpg">
  <div class="nav-container">
    <!-- nav stuff -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Within that same container I'd like to have a nav menu and possibly some hero text, but I'd like it all to be constrained to a 1200px wide, centered `<div>`. Normally I would achieve that by doing something like:

```
.header {
  position: relative;
}

.header img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.header .nav-container {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

Naturally, with this CSS the `<img>` element pushes the nav down. The problem is, as soon as I stick `position: absolute;` in the nav CSS, it no longer centers. It seems to honour the max-width of 1200px, but it doesn't "float" in the center of the header anymore. It just goes left or right depending on my top/left/right values.

**TL;DR - How can I have a 1200px div centered above a full-width image element?**

Comment: Why don't you set the width to 100% and keep max-width at 1200px? Even not centering there can be a few quirks with the width on absolute elements, they try to stay as small as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can center an absolutely positioned element horizontally by using a combination of `left: 50%;` and `transform: translateX(-50%);`. Here's a demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZLGKmo

Comment: Is this technique fairly well supported among the major browsers?